# When utilizing IBM hpc-cluster api, how do I authenticate with IAM Token?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud

JSON response when trying to make an API call. I keep getting "IAM Token passed is invalid."

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "IAM Token passed is invalid.",
    "transaction_id": "257a01a1-cfa2-4fbf-b6bc-5abd1fd820f7"
  },
  "success": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to renew your IAM Token and not use any previous or someone else's token to make a call.

Following are the CLI commands to follow to log into IBM cloud and generate a new IAM token.

```
ibmcloud login
ibmcloud iam oauth-tokens
```

Doc link: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-monitoring/security/auth_iam.html#auth_iam

To work with the API, the user should add IBM Cloud IAM access token in the API request authentication header:

```
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <IAM_TOKEN>'
```